# Möbius transformation of Algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I am working on the uniformization of algebraic curve problem.

Currently, my adviser gave me a question about building a Möbius transformation between algebraic curves, and then lifting it to the Riemann surface.

My question is how does one build a Möbius transformation between algebraic curves? How does this transformation make sense?

Say that I have curve $y^2 = x^2 - 1$, and my first idea is mapping $(x, y) \rightarrow (1/x, y)$, then I would have $y^2 = (1/x)^2 - 1$, but my adviser said it doesn't make sense.

So any one could gave me an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Would $(x,y)\to(1/x,y/x)$ be better? Then you can rewrite the curve without changing its degree.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right! Any idea how to build the Mobius transformation?

Comment: My guess (which shouldn't be taken too strongly since I've no formal background in algebraic curves) is that you'd take the mapping on $x$ to be a Mobius transformation, and then choose the mapping on $y$ so as to give a sensible curve.